# Using Struts 2 builtin JSON utility class

Tags: java, json, struts2

In an Struts 2 project, we need to serialize and deserialize objects, as our requirement is very simple, we decide to use Struts 2 `JSONUtil` instead of `gson`.

```
import org.apache.struts2.json;

String json = JSONUtil.serialize(myAccountVO);
// return: {"accountNumber":"0105069413007","amount":"1500","balance":"215000"}
```

For `deserialization`, we face the `class cast exception`

```
    AccountVO vo =(AccountVO) JSONUtil.deserialize(json);
    //Exception
```

I find that the `deserialization` returns a map with key value of object properties. So I must do as:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap) JSONUtil.deserialize(string)
accountVo.setAccountNumber(map.get("accountNumber"));
....
```

Well can I do it better or I am expecting too much from this utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have deserialized JSON, you can use [`JSONPopulator`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-plugins/struts2-json-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/json/JSONPopulator.html) to populate bean properties from a map. E.g.

```
JSONPopulator populator = new JSONPopulator();
AccountVO vo = new AccountVO();
populator.populateObject(vo, map);
```