# Using Struts 2 builtin JSON utility class for List objects

Tags: java, json, struts2

I can use struts built in json converters to serialize and deserialize json. As asked at: [Using Struts 2 builtin JSON utility class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822495/using-struts-2-builtin-json-utility-class)

```
JSONPopulator populator = new JSONPopulator();
SampleVO vo = new SampleVO();
populator.populateObject(vo, map);
```

But It dose not work with `list`, for example:

```
List<SampleVO> listSamples = new ArrayList<>();
populator.populateObject(listSamples, map);
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

I found that there are `convertToCollection` and `convertToArray` methods in `JSONPopulator, they are private, and I don't know if this util class can help me?